# How to create a Refresh and Stop for a single UIBarbutton

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a `webView` where i need to display refresh/stop for single Button that need to change vice versa. when user click refresh the button need to display stop icon until the `webView` finish loads and display back refresh icon after loading the view.I need and approach to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this first declare one global button like this

```
var button: UIButton = UIButton()
```

Now create one function like this

```
func setRefreshItem() {
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 25)
    //Set backgroundImage in button for both state Normal and selected 
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Refresh"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Stop"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshWebView(_:))",forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    let rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem
}
```

Now add `refreshWebView` method in your `viewController`

```
func refreshWebView(sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.selected) {
        self.webView.stopLoading() 
    }
    else {
        self.webView.reload() 
    }
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}

//Delegate method of webView
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
    self.buttton.selected = false
}
```

Also call `setRefreshItem` in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways of doing that. You can declare another variable in your ViewController named "allowsRefresh", and then when you click on the button, you can do something like

```
@IBAction refreshOrStop(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (allowsRefresh) {
        // Do stuff that refreshes the webpage
    } else {
        // Do stuff that stops the refresh
    }
    allowsRefresh = !allowsRefresh 
    // Inverse itself. If it was true, change it false. If it was false, change it to true
}
```

There are certainly better names than allowsRefresh, but you get the point.